# DXA 1.5 (java) build error

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, dxa-1.5

I tried to build DXA 1.5 distribution these days, but it has errors like below:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project cea-webapp: Could not
>   resolve dependencies for project
>   com.cea.dxa:cea-webapp:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect
>   dependencies at com.sdl.dxa:dxa-web8-provider:jar:1.5.0 ->
>   com.sdl.web:cil:pom:8.2.0-1011 -> com.sdl.web:xo-client:jar:8.2.0 ->
>   com.sdl.web:content-client-api:jar:8.2.0-1008: Failed to read artifact
>   descriptor for com.sdl.web:content-client-api:jar:8.2.0-1008: Could
>   not transfer artifact com.sdl.web:content-client-api:pom:8.2.0-1008
>   from/to local-project-repo
>   (file:///${project.basedir}/../../local-project-repo): Repository path
>   /${project.basedir}/../../local-project-repo does not exist, and
>   cannot be created.

my steps to build my solution are:

1. download dxa-web-application-java-release-1.5 from github
2. run `gradlew.sh`
3. generate my web application cea-webapp by using dxa-webapp-archetype
4. Add dependencies into pom of cea-webapp, such as dxa common api, dxa existing modules, spring related,
5. build cea-webapp. when building it, error occurs as above.

Can anybody tell me what's wrong with me?

Comment: Can you post your `pom.xml` here http://pastebin.com/?

Answer (score 3):

It tries to get a dependency `com.sdl.web:content-client-api:jar:8.2.0-1008` which doesn't exist in Maven Central. `com.sdl.web:xo-client:jar:8.2.0` is dependent on it. The problem can be workarounded if you specify an explicit dependency in your Webapp's pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sdl.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>content-client-api</artifactId>
    <version>8.2.0-1009</version>
</dependency>
```

It that's not enough, also exclude it from CIL.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sdl.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>cil</artifactId>
    <type>pom</type>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.sdl.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>content-client-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

## UPDATE:

The issue with content-client-api is fixed and 1008 version is now available in Maven Central. http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.sdl.web%7Ccontent-client-api%7C8.2.0-1008%7Cjar

If it doesn't resolve, try cleaning your Maven repository, the previous attempt may be cached.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen errors like `Repository path /${project.basedir}/../../local-project-repo does not exist, and cannot be created.` before when building on a Mac. Try to add a `local-project-repo` repo to your pom and point it to an existing empty directory.

add this to your pom

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>local-project-repo</id>
        <url>file:///${project.basedir}/local-project-repo</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: `local-project-repo` contains artifacts which are intentionally not in Maven Central (for any reason), like e.g. custom DD4T. Since CIL is a public stuff, this has nothing related to `local-project-repo`

Comment: Indeed, the error message is a bit misleading because it blames this last resort (the local repo), but the root cause was a wrong dependency version in Maven Central.